# Change an image downloaded from the web into a CarouselView when the displayed item changes

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a `CarouselView` with an image and a Label inside. Each time I change an element, a new text and a new image are displayed. The text is already inside a List and is retrieved from there, while the image is retrieved from my web space, so every time an element is changed, the `CarouselView` freezes for an instant to load the new image. I would like to find a way, if there is one, to initially display the image blurry, and then download all the data necessary to display it correctly so that the `CarouselView` does not freeze.
In the `DataTemplate` of the `CarouselView` I use the `FFImageLoading` extension.

c#:

```
private void Carousel_CurrentItemChanged (object sender, CurrentItemChanged e)
{
    string Words = "New Text";
    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    web.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ( "xx", "xxx");
    
    string image = "ftp://.......jpg";
    byte[] ImgByte = web.DownloadData(image);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    MyImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStrem(()=> stream);
}
```

EDIT:

[Example](https://1drv.ms/v/s!ApEbJKXRW_xfjBjwkOkNt_Gt5nCs?e=fCf9lI)

Comment: FF has a loading placeholder feature - or you could pre-fetch your images to avoid the delay

Comment: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Xamarin.Forms-API#c

Comment: I have not solved my problem with the PlaceHolder because the CarouselView still crashes. I just posted a video with my example

Comment: "still crashes" - you didn't mention a **crash** anywhere in your post.

Comment: the CarouselView freezes for a moment. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: don't do an expensive network operation in the ItemChanged handler.  Do it in a background task, or pre-load the images, or something else